# How to use maki icon in layout:{ }

Tags: mapbox

I install maki by
npm install @mapbox/maki --save

Then
I add geojson layer, want to use icon wetland, as below,

```
          "layout": {
                                     "icon-image": "wetland-11",
                                }
```

It is not working! But only monument works. Why????

```
                         "layout": {
                                     "icon-image": "monument-11",
                                }
```

I end up use add image layer as icon,

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/

Comment: most of maki icon are not working, only monument, ancher works.

Comment: also, map.addimage() does not support svg. only support png, jpg etc.....

Comment: if you download maki, all of them are svg, will not be able to use map.addimage()

Comment: Which Mapbox streets tilesets are you currently using? Not all Maki icons in the public repo are supported in the Mapbox streets v8 style specification. ⚠️ Disclaimer: I work at Mapbox ⚠️

Comment: Is there a list of which maki icons work and which don't? That would be really helpful!